# SOQL with duplicate results

Tags: soql

I am working on a data load to load multiple opportunities for an account. I am provided with a spreadsheet with the Contract Number (unique custom field on Account). So, I need to query the Account object with Contract_Number__c, but I want duplicate results also. For ex, if the Contract Number appears on the spread sheet for 3 rows, I need to insert 3 opportunities for the account. I am trying the below soql.

```
Select Id, OwnerId, Contract_Number__c 
from Account 
where Contract_Number__c in ('000-001-001', '000-001-001', '000-001-002').
```

The above query is returning only 2 records as below.

```
Id                        OwnerId                   Contract_Number__c
000112231412adfad         004313143413131aaa        000-001-001
00011223413432fae         00431343143ac3ffae        000-001-002
```

However, I need the results as below.

```
Id                        OwnerId                   Contract_Number__c
000112231412adfad             004313143413131aaa        000-001-001
000112231412adfad             004313143413131aaa        000-001-001
00011223413432fae             00431343143ac3ffae        000-001-002
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If the `Contract_Number__c` field on `Account` has the 'unique' property (as I think you're saying), then it is impossible to have the same value of `Contract_Number__c` appear on more than one `Account`.

Comment: If each row in your spreadsheet represents an Opportunity, you should probably just insert each of those rows as an Opportunity record. If you would like to use the `Contract Number` value in your spreadsheet row as the key that links the `Opportunity` to the `Account` you can do so via the External ID functionality (with the assumption that `Contract_Number__c` on `Account` is marked as an external id field).